# Why does a property attribute returns empty using a model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller and a model.

Now, I wanted to get the property of a model from the controller, but I can not access it. Here is my code:

**MODEL**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function isRole()
    {
        return $this->role; //mysql column role
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{ 
    public function index()
    {
        $user = new User;
        return $user->isRole(); //this is just to test display the role column. but it returns empty or no value.
    }
}
```

I also tried to echo `$this->role` inside the function `isRole()`, but again it is empty. In my database, I have values inserted on `role` column.

I also executed the php artisan migrate in order to update the data.

Somebody help me: what's going on here? thanks

Comment: You're just instantiating a new User model in PHP memory, with no retrieval from the db at all, so it doesn't matter what records you have on the database

Answer (score 3):

In your code:

```
$user = new User;
return $user->isRole();
```

You're creating a User out of nothing, so the role will be garbage. Try the following to get the first user of your table:

```
$user = User::firstOrFail();
return $user->isRole();
```

Note that if the table is empty, `firstOrFail` will throw an exception.

**EDIT:**

As stated in [shukshin.ivan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801631/why-does-a-property-attribute-returns-empty-on-model/45801694?noredirect=1#comment78562081_45801694), users can also be filtered using a `where` clause like the following:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
return $user->isRole();
```

Comment: thanks it makes sense. How about if I am going to get the data with email address? here is my user :  `$user = User::where('email', $request->email)` How should I get the column based on that email address?

Comment: Get the first (it is unique) matched user `$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first()`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = App\User::find(1);

        return $user->isRole();
    }
```

you get empty value because `new User();` is empty